# Tableau Server Could not locate unexpired trusted ticket local network

Tags: tableau-api

I have two servers , Server #1 one hosted in the office using the office network (this hosts the  tableau server on ubuntu server) and the  other server Server #2 sitting in another collocated network. The web application is hosted in server #2 and the tableau dashboards are embended on the web application.

When I try to access the application from another public network , the  dashboards are working very well, however when I try to access the dashboards from the  office network (which hosts the  tablueau server ), I get the  following error  =>

[image: Could not locate unexpired trusted ticket]

Answer (score 0):

That error is generally caused by one of two issues

1. The IP Address of Webserver hosting the IFrame was not whitelisted under Trusted Authentication in TSM or [Add Trusted IP Addresses or Host Names to Tableau Server](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_trustIP.htm)

or

2. The trusted user does not exist on the Tableau server and/or the username does not match what was passed to the webserver from your web application hosting the Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

We have trusted_ticket_expiry set to 240 minutes.

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/changing-the-expiration-timeout-of-trusted-tickets

Answer (score 0):

For me, there were 2 issues:

1. The script type was text/javascript:

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js"></script>
   ```

whereas the type should be **module**

```
    <script type="module" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js"></script>
```

2. I was using the **tableau-react** plugin instead of the **tableau-viz** plugin and **tableau-react** was for some reason not working properly.
   So I switched back to **tableau-viz** and it started working.

If you are using react with typescript, you might get **Property 'tableau-viz' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)** error,
which you can resolve by adding below line in index.d.ts

```
    declare namespace JSX {
      interface IntrinsicElements {
        'tableau-viz': any
      }
    }
```